# Android Studio: Error: SplashActivity is not an Activity subclass or alias

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a library project which has all functionality and some activities, and I also have a wrapper activity which only has a JSON configuration string and some styling. I imported the library to the wrapper project, and in the wrapper project I'm setting one of the library's activities as the launch activity, but then get an error that the selected activity from the library is not **an activity subclass or alias**.

What does that mean and can I correct this?

**The Activity that is supposed to be launched:**

```
package dk.borgertip.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import dk.borgertip.R;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Thread startTimer = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        startTimer.start();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_splash, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**The project structure:** (The Borgertip module is the library that contains the activity to launch which extends **Activity**)

[image: The Borgertip module is the library that contains the activity to launch]

**The 'Edit Configuration' dialog with the error:**

[image]

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Where is `myActivity` ?

Comment: myActivity is just a general notation I used for the title. I corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the `activity` in your project AndroidManifest.xml

Source official [doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject):

```
In the manifest file of the application project, you must add declarations 
of all components that the application will use that are imported from a 
library project. For example, you must declare any <activity>, <service>, 
<receiver>, <provider>, and so on, as well as <permission>, 
<uses-library>, and similar elements.
```

Comment: Very curious about the downvote (3 years after!) :-)

Comment: I suspect most people from Google come across this problem because they messed up the build configurations as @Sandoval shows below.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, in this particular case it was caused after refactoring some code and delete the activity that was set as the application main activity.

I made sure the `<activity></activity>` declaration was also removed from the `manifest.xml` file but it was still set as the main activity whitin the `Run/Debug configurations` section in Android Studio.

Just go to `run/Edit configurations.../Android App/app`

Select the `"General"` tab and look at the `"Launch Options"` section. There you can choose the activity you want to set as the main one.

**Hope this will be useful for someone else.**

Comment: Thank you I was becoming crazy ! Same problem as you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem before. Maybe too late but there is a rare situation that triggers this problem. If you choose a specific activity to run with in the launch options and you deleted or renamed the activity. So just check your app launch option. Maybe it helps someone !

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Tools** ---> **Edit Configurations** and then **Select the Activity Class** File Again.

This will Fix this Issue.

Comment: THAT WAS IT!! !

Answer (score 0):

Details

As @Gabriele pointed out, the `Activity` to be launched must be specified in `AndroidManifest.xml` and also, as @Sandova noted, the `Configurations` section.

The manifest should look something like this:

`<manifest ... package="com.`
***whatever***`.`**project_name**`" >`

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />`


   `<application   android:label="whatever1" android:theme="whatever2"
      <activity  android:label="whatever3" 
                 android:name="com.`
***whatever***`.`***project_name***`.`***name_of_your_activity***`" >`

```
        <intent-filter>
              <action   android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

To specify the name of the activity in the `Configuration` section, go to `Run > Edit Configurations` and expand `Android App` to find `app`.

Note the `Launch Options` section and select `Specified Activity` from the `Launch` menu, which then will show the textbox in which the name of the activity must be specified.

As suggested by OP's `Edit Configuration dialog`, the `Activity` to launch must be *fully qualified*--i.e., `SplashActivity` isn't enough. (Clicking the `...` at the far right of the textbox might be helpful if needed.)